# Classification Theorem for Non-Compact 2-Manifolds? 2-Manifolds With Boundary?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I recently learned about the Classification Theorem for compact 2-manifolds.  Is there a similar classification theorem for ALL 2-manifolds, not just the compact ones?

Moreover, is there a theorem which classifies the 2-manifolds with boundary?

Comment: Any open subset of R^2 is a 2-manifold, so my impression is that this classification is hopeless in general.

Comment: It's pretty fussy but not quite hopeless.  That's one of the most interesting things about doing mathematics -- in that you get to see the blurry line where "hard" problems live evolve and take shape, some problems become "doable" and some become "hopeless", some stay mysteriously "hard" and never budge...

Comment: For the classification of compact connected 2-manifolds with boundary, you can look at Massey's "Algebraic Topology. An introduction". Notice that "the other" Massey, "Basic course in Algebraic Topology", though merging the former with his "Singular homology theory", does no longer contain the aforementioned classification.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there's a classification theorem for non-compact 2-manifolds.

This paper gives the classification for triangulable 2-manifolds:

http://www.jstor.org/stable/1993768

That an arbitrary (2nd countable, Hausdorff) topological 2-manifold admits a triangulation is fairly classical.  Ahlfors book "Riemann Surfaces" has a proof.  There are others available, see for example this list:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17578/triangulating-surfaces

If all you're interested in is compact manifolds with boundary, you get that classification immediately from the closed manifold case.  Because if you have a compact manifold with boundary, its boundary is a disjoint union of circles.  So cap those circles off with discs to produce a closed manifold.  So compact manifolds with boundary are classified by the closed manifold you get by "capping off" and the number of boundary circles you started with.

Non-compact manifolds have a more delicate classification -- think for example about the complement of a Cantor set in a compact surface.

Comment: Should I interpret that complement of the Cantor set is taken account of by the classification theorem in the first paper that you have linked to?

Comment: Yes, that's included in this classification.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a summary of the situation regarding noncompact $2$-manifolds with boundary, thanks to [Moishe Kohan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/84907/moishe-kohan) and [Jacques Darné](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/611408/j-darn%C3%A9).

Originally, I posted an answer pointing to the 2007 paper [*Classification of noncompact surfaces with boundary* by A. O. Prishlyak and K. I. Mischenko, Methods Funct. Anal. Topology 13 (2007), no. 1, 62–66](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2308580).  However, Kohan pointed out that the classification had actually been completed much earlier by E. Brown and R. Messer ([*The classification of two-dimensional manifolds*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 255 (1979), 377–402](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1979-255-00/S0002-9947-1979-0542887-1/S0002-9947-1979-0542887-1.pdf)). Then more recently Darné pointed out that the theorem claimed by Prishlyak and Mischenko is false, because it contradicts the one of Brown and Messer. See Darné's comment below for details.

So the upshot is that the correct classification of noncompact $2$-manifolds with boundary was completed in 1979 by Brown and Messer in the paper cited above.

Comment: Actually, this classification of noncompact surfaces with boundary was completed in 1979: E. Brown and R. Messer, "The classification of two-dimensional manifolds", Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., vol. 255 (1979), 377–402. Just Prishlyak and  Mischenko were unaware of that paper.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: Wow. I was unaware of it too. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JackLee For further reference, you should edit your answer: the theorem of Prishlyak and Mischenko is false. In fact, it contradicts the one of Brown and Messer, and examples in the latter paper show that their invariants are not strong enough. Precisely, they only take connected components of the graph of non-compact connected components, when they should consider the whole graph, with some chosen (equivalence class of) orientation. Also, their claim that connected components of the graph can only be circles is not true at all (cf. the introduction of Brown and Messer).

Comment: @J.Darné -- at this point, maybe it will be best if you write a separate answer and I delete mine, since my answer is now mainly disinformation.

Comment: @JackLee Well, you can edit yours if you like, to turn it into information! After all, it has been useful to me: I am just beginning to read about this stuff, and I was unaware of the paper of Brown and Messer. But if you prefer, I can also write an answer. As you wish :)