# Classifying plane regions by their fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

The Riemann mapping theorem in complex analysis implies that any two simply connected open subsets of $\mathbb C$ are homeomorphic.

Does anybody know if there is a more general theorem along the lines of: "Two connected open subsets of $\mathbb C$ are homeomorphic iff they have the same fundamental groups"?

I have never seen this written down, and yet, it is very difficult to come up with a counterexample. The examples I'm coming up with all look like an annulus with multiple holes - for these examples, the statement is obviously true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Consider $S=R^2 - {\mathbb Z}\times \{0\}$ as one surface; as the other surface consider $S - \{\frac{1}{n}: n\in {\mathbb N}\}$. Both surfaces have free groups of countably infinite rank, but they are not homeomorphic. (To prove the latter you need the *theory of ends*. You can also take a look at the references [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/classification-theorem-for-non-compact-2-manifolds-2-manifolds-with-boundary?noredirect=1&lq=1)). On the other hand, if you consider only domains in $R^2$ with finitely generated fundamental groups then indeed the fundamental group (or even just the 1st Betti number) determines the surface up to homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!

Comment: are you sure that the second example has countable fundamental group ?

Comment: @mercio: Yes, every CW complex with countably many cells has countable fundamental group. In the case of surfaces: Each open connected surface is homotopy equivalent to a bouquet of at most countably many circles. I think you are confusing this example with Hawaiian earrings.

Comment: are you saying it's not homotopy equivalent to a hawaiian earring ? 
(yeah i'm possibly very confused)

Comment: @mercio: Yes, it is not h.e. to H.E..

Comment: I just now realized it was $S$ minus stuff and not $R^2$ minus stuff, and since $(0,0)$ is removed..... yeah.